# Recursively generate LaTeX expression for continued fractions for a given python list

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, latex, mathjax, continued-fractions

I am trying to generate `LaTeX` string expression for continued fractions in `Jupyter Notebook`.
for example, a given Python list `x=[1,2,3,4,5]` can be written as continued fraction:

[image]

Structure expression to generate this `LaTeX` fraction is `\\frac{Numerator}{Denominator}`

With Non-recursive code :

```py
from IPython.display import display, Markdown

# Non-recursive: 
def nest_frac(previous_expr, numerator_expr1, denominator_expr2):
    return previous_expr + " + \\frac{"+ numerator_expr1 + "}{" + denominator_expr2 + "}"

# Cumbersome, error-prone
display(Markdown("$"+ \
                 nest_frac("1","1", \
                           nest_frac("2","1", \
                                     nest_frac("3","1", \
                                              nest_frac("4","1", "5") \
                                              )  \
                                     ) \
                          ) \
            + "$") \
       )

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

How to recursively generate expression provided a python list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can define the function `nest_frac_N` taking `x` as an additional argument:

```
def nest_frac_N(previous_expr, numerator_expr1, denominator_expr2, x):
    
    temp_frac=str(x[len(x)-1]-1) +"+  \\frac{"+str(numerator_expr1)+"}{"+str(x[len(x)-1])+"}"
    
    for i in reversed(x[:len(x)-2]):
        
        temp_frac = str(i) +"+  \\frac{1}{"+temp_frac+"}"
    
    return temp_frac
```

If we need an output for `x=[1,2,3,4,5]` we do:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> nest_frac_N(1, 1, 1, x)
... '1+  \\frac{1}{2+  \\frac{1}{3+  \\frac{1}{4+  \\frac{1}{5}}}}'
```

To get the markdown format we use :

```
display(Markdown("$"+nest_frac_N(1, 1, 1, x)+"$"))
```

Let's the `x` size to 10 to ensure that function is flexible :

**Output**

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> nest_frac_N(1, 1, 1, x)
... '1+  \\frac{1}{2+  \\frac{1}{3+  \\frac{1}{4+  \\frac{1}{5+  \\frac{1}{6+  \\frac{1}{7+  \\frac{1}{8+  \\frac{1}{9+  \\frac{1}{10}}}}}}}}}'
```

And to get the markdown :

```
display(Markdown("$"+nest_frac_N(1, 1, 1, x)+"$"))
```

And we can easily re-set the function in a way to display directly the markdown format.

Comment: Please note, `x` has to be a python list.

Comment: @RajeshSwarnkar please take a look at the new edits

Comment: Looks like there is bug. Please check. It gives wrong result for input `x=[2,2,1,1,2]` but output has `x=[2,2,1,1,1,2]` and extra 1. Also, this solution is non-recursive.

Comment: @RajeshSwarnkar please check the new edit, I replaced `for i in reversed(x[:len(x)-1])` by `for i in reversed(x[:len(x)-2])`, now it should work

Comment: OP asked: _"How to **recursively** generate expression provided a python list."_  I'm not suggesting this is a bad method for creating the LaTeX string, but it isn't a solution to the problem as it was stated.